# running PS script from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

i have a PS file which has below line of code

```
 $machineDomain = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
```

when calling this script from C# , i get the error `System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Get-WmiObject' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet`

Script runs fine when run in Powershell window but is throwing exception when running from C#.

C# code

```
    using System.Management.Automation;

    private void RunValidationScript(string scriptFilePath)
    {
        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            var resultsN = ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(scriptFilePath)).Invoke();
        }
    }
```

I tried below nuget packages with either and both but no help

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK
System.Management.Automation
```

Please help

Comment: looks like a problem in `System.Management.Automation` but I'm not quite sure

Comment: Did you try to explicitly load `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` to have that cmdlet available? Automatic loading might not work when working from C#.

Comment: @Seth , Not sure how to do that. can you please show code for it?

Comment: `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` in your PS code.